# More efficient css: background image or background rgba?

Tags: css

### Which is more efficient:

I'm trying to find out which method of providing a semi transparent background is more efficient/faster:

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .12);
```

Or

```
background-image: url('/path/to/semi-transparent/pixel.png');
```

Couldn't find any resources.

I understand that the `background-color` one doesn't require an HTTP request and that the `background-image` takes more processing.

---

### Notes:

Compatibility is a big issue as I (no one really should) can't drop support for < IE8.

A lot of answers/comments are mentioning that the `background-color: rgba` is faster and more efficient but that `background-image` is more compatibility friendly. If true (haven't seen any hard tests) then: is there a fallback solution other than using a library like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) that will work? i.e. (this does not work as it does both at the same time - but looking for something along these lines)

```
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .12) url('/path/to/semi-transparent/pixel.png');
```

Comment: `efficient` and `faster` means different to me. However `rgba()` is not supported in IE8 and below. You might want to consider the second approach as a fallback of the first one.

Comment: Other than adding a library like Modernizer or doing browser detection - is there any way to do that? (Not being supported by `< IE8` is a deal breaker so I will use the `background-image`)

Comment: Absolutely the first approach. The second requires another HTTP request to be performed.

Comment: Implementation-dependent, but processing an image (even a tiny one) and handling its repetition is probably slightly more expensive to prepare and render.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the first one would be faster. Using an image will use an additional HTTP request to fetch it, also the size of the image would affect the loading time. Using hex color values instead of rgb would also be better as the browser ultimately converts rgb to hex.

Comment: Correct on the first part, but saying hex colors are faster than `rgba()` doesn’t make any sense. Hex is a string representation of some bytes; the browser has to convert either one back and forth to them regardless of representation. (But only once, so any difference would be negligible.) And then there’s the fact that you can’t represent transparent colours in hex in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the first is more efficient and fast. The latter is a more compatible option and should be used if the first, more efficient method does not work with the browsers you want it to work with.

Comment: I'm looking for a test, for proof :) - also, if the `rgba` is faster, how do I handle fallback without using something like `Modernizr` ?